# Is there a list of narrow-use adjectives (which can only be used with certain nouns)?

Tags: adjectives

e.g. I have never heard 'inclement' being used to refer to anything other than 'inclement weather'. Is there a list somewhere of these types of narrow-use adjectives?

Comment: Good question. I looked, but did not find . . . Try searching "strong collocation" "inclement weather" and see if that inspires anything.